# Select multiple items from DropDownList into TextBox, No duplicates

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, web-applications, drop-down-menu

i used the following technique to Select multiple items from DropDownList into TextBox with No duplicates, however i dont think it is the most proper way, any ideas.

[image]

pressing again with same value selected

[image]

choose another value from DDL and press button

[image]

here is my code

```
Protected Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    If TextBox2.Text.Contains(DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text) Then
        Dim m As New Label
        m.Text = "duplicate !"
        Me.form1.Controls.Add(m)
        Exit Sub

    End If
    If TextBox2.Text = "" Then
        TextBox2.Text = DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text
    Else
        TextBox2.Text = TextBox2.Text + " , " + DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The logic looks pretty correct to me. The only thing I'd do different something like:

```
Protected Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
   If TextBox2.Text.Contains(DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text) Then
     Dim m As New Label
     m.Text = "duplicate !"
     Me.form1.Controls.Add(m)
   Else If TextBox2.Text = "" Then
     TextBox2.Text = DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text
   Else
     TextBox2.Text = TextBox2.Text + " , " + DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text
   End If
End Sub
```

I'd make the construct and `If..else if...else` and avoid the premature return. It is prefered to program functions with only one exit point, for clarity. There's no reason why not to in this case.